# increment a for loop by 1 then by 2

Tags: c++, for-loop, increment

I need to increment a for loop by 1, then by 2, then by 1 in this cycle. I have a method to do it but I don't like it. Does anyone have a 'nicer' implementation than this:

```
int value= 2;
int changeValue=1;
for(int i=0;i<m;i+=value){
  value+=(changeValue*-1);
 }
```

the language is c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has an accepted answer, but nobody mentioned this, so I figured I would add an extra response:

The indexes you get by choosing a 2-1-2-1-2-1-2-1 step are these:

```
0,   2, 3,   5, 6,   8, 9, ...
```

You can easily see that every third index is missing, starting from 1. The easiest way to write this ("easiest" = "most clear to read for a developer, later") would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    if(i % 3 == 1)
        continue;
    // handle rest of loop
}
```

There is no extra step variable here, and although you also iterate for the skipped indexes, the iteration will not matter for performance, unless you are looking at performance-critical code.

Comment: Simple and effective. Loop through all but don't take action on these:...  keeps the loop simple, and the guard clause is a common design pattern.  I'd expect that there would not be any problem with performance even with performance critical code, optimisation and branch prediction (2 on 1 off is simple enough to be covered) should handle this as well as any other method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < m; i += (j++ % 2) + 1) {
    //...
}
```

There are no operations in cycle's body.

Answer (score 1):

I would make something clear like this

```
  int i = 0;
  bool twice = false;

  while (i < m) {

    // code here                                                                

    if (!twice) {
      twice = true;
      i++;
    } else {
      twice = false;
      i += 2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution in my opinion would be to unroll the loop:

```
int value= 2;
int changeValue=1;
for(int i=0;i<m;i+=value){
    foo(i);
    value+=(changeValue*-1);
}
```

becomes:

```
foo(0);
for(int i=1;i<m;i+=3){
    foo(i);
    foo(i+2)
}
```

This way, you add no extra computation overhead to calculate the increment of the loop index

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess you could make it a little bit more neat like this:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i += j++ % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1 ) {
    //
}
```

Surely it isn't the most readable, it would need a little comment around, but it's short